# symfony2 container anonymous functions

Tags: php, symfony, containers

Is it possible to use anonymous functions to register factories in symphony2?

For example:

```
use Foo\Baz;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;

$baz = new Definition(Baz::class);

$baz->setFactory(function(){
    return new Baz();
});

$container->setDefinition(Baz::class, $baz);
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am currently using Symfony 2.8

Comment: Have you tried it?  I did not find anything in the docs but the code should work if it gets past the type check argument.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are describing has been available [since Symfony v2.6.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.6.0/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php#L67) - however you obviously can't set closures/anonymous-functions via XML or YAML, so probably the best place to set closure factories is in your [bundle's extension class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class).